# How to run a python script on server X times simultaneously?

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous, server

I have seen a ton of people asking how to run python blocking code blocks synchronously. However, everyone is giving different answers of what to do. What is arguably the best way to run a function (one with blocking code) many times simultaneously in python? Additionally, if it is on a server rather than just a local computer. I am also using Selenium, so it will be opening up a chrome.exe every time it is ran.

Comment: This depends heavily on your use case, which is why you don't see a definitive answer. Your problem might perfectly work with threading or asyncio, but you might also need `multiprocessing` (which is heavier in terms of overall resource usage).

Comment: @wkl I will be using selenium which will being opening up a chrome.exe every time the function is ran.

Comment: Still something you're going to have to test for your specific workload (and it's not really difficult to switch between using threads or multiprocessing unless you're doing some stuff like relying heavily on shared memory/IPC). If your code is going to spend most of its time doing I/O work (e.g., network transfer) then threads are probably 'good enough'. If your code does a lot of CPU-heavy work after all the I/O stuff, then you'll probably want to use multiprocessing.